# risc-v ld cannot find libc and libgloss

Tags: linker, ld, libc, riscv, toolchain

I use window10 with WSL, linux version is ubuntu20.0.4

When I use riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -lc --verbose to check some information,

The log is as follows :

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: riscv64-unknown-elf
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --libexecdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --target=riscv64-unknown-elf --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/doc/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf/html --pdfdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf/pdf --bindir=/usr/bin --libexecdir=/usr/lib --libdir=/usr/lib --with-pkgversion= --disable-shared --disable-threads --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-tls --with-newlib --with-native-system-header-dir=/include --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libgomp --disable-nls --with-system-zlib --enable-checking=yes --enable-multilib --with-abi=lp64d --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx --disable-fixinc --with-arch=rv64imafdc --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-as=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld AR_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ar AS_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/as NM_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/nm LD_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/objdump RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ranlib READELF_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/readelf STRIP_FOR_TARGET=/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/strip CFLAGS='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-3seJsn/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-9.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong' CPPFLAGS='-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-3seJsn/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-9.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong' FCFLAGS='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-3seJsn/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-9.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong' FFLAGS='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-3seJsn/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-9.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong' GCJFLAGS='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-3seJsn/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-9.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong' LDFLAGS='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' OBJCFLAGS='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-3seJsn/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-9.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong' OBJCXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-3seJsn/gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf-9.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong' 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-Os -mcmodel=medany' 'CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-Os -mcmodel=medany'
Thread model: single
gcc version 9.3.0 () 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/:/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/rv64imafdc/lp64d/:/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-march=rv64imafdc' '-mabi=lp64d'
 /usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc2p9LDX.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgloss -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -melf64lriscv crt0.o /usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/rv64imafdc/lp64d/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/rv64imafdc/lp64d -L/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0 -lc -lgcc --start-group -lc -lgloss --end-group -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/9.3.0/rv64imafdc/lp64d/crtend.o
/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/lib/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgloss
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I lose the libc and libgloss, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hello, did you build newlib?

Comment: I found that llvm repo don't contain newlib, I need build it by my self. Thanks.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgloss